# WPF Resize Window proportionally ie. No stretching or distorting?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Window which contains a Grid. It's set up to look like a Checkers board, so I need the squares of the grid to stay square when the window is resized.

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work. I hope it's just a matter of getting the right attribute, and not something complicated, but I need it to resize proportionally either way.

I'm also not sure if this should happen in the Grid or in the Window. I would assume the Window because that's the controller for resizing, but I could be wrong. 
Any suggestions?

xaml for Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TicTacToeClient.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicTacToeClient"
    Title="Mini-Checkers V1.1" Height="600" Width="600" 
      MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200" MaxHeight="600" MaxWidth="600" >
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Game">
            <MenuItem Header="Set Ip Address" Name="IPAddressMenuItem"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Set Name" Name="SetNameMenuItem"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text ="Status: " Name="GameStatusBar" />
    <local:TicTacToeBoard x:Name="GameBoard" />
</DockPanel>
```

xaml for Grid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TicTacToeClient.TicTacToeBoard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600">

<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `DataBinding` the `Width` of your `Grid` to the `Height` (or vice-versa).  This will make sure that it always grows proportionally.  Something as simple as this should work:

```
<Grid x:Name="Checkerboard" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} Path=ActualHeight}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <!-- Grid Contents -->
</Grid>
```

And if you want your cells to all remain square, just make sure they're all * sized, so they will be spread out equally.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can put yor grid inside a `Viewbox` with `Stretch="Uniform"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try enclosing your`GameBoard` in a [`ViewBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617883%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with [`Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Property set to [`Uniform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`StretchDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretchdirection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) set to Both.  like this. It wont keep the Form's Aspect ratio uniform but will keep your GameBoard Proportions Uniform.

```
<Viewbox  Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
    <local:TicTacToeBoard x:Name="GameBoard" />
</Viewbox>
```